# Apple Documentation diagramming convention

Tags: cocoa, documentation

I am reading Apple's Documentation and API reference. Where can I read the diagramming conventions used to draw the object diagrams in the documentation? Example of a diagram:
[image: a diagram]

Answer (score 2):

I would be surprised if that's a formal convention - the diagram is just illustrating **relations between** various (model, controller and view) **objects**.

The kind of relation is described by the label.

Not quite sure what the background of your question is?
Do you want to write documentation similar to Apple's..??

Comment: Ditto. I don't believe Apple's documentation follows any formal graphical language (like [UML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) or some such, though it's clearly at least somewhat UML-influenced) -- they just draw whatever makes the concepts they're trying to illustrate most clear. If you're looking for tools to help draw these kinds of diagrams, I suggest [OmniGraffle](http://omnigroup.com/graffle).

Comment: @Jay No, I want to know which lines, arrows and boxes are used when so that I can also understand and practice drawing

Comment: @Rounak: I see - for creating your own diagrams common standards like [UML](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language) are probably still first choice?